# LaTeX extra } issue

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I'm trying to compile a document that uses BibLaTeX with the Biber backend, but I keep getting these errors on the last line of my document:

```
! Argument of \hyper@anchorstart has an extra }.<inserted text>\par \end
! Paragraph ended before \hyper@anchorstart was complete.<to be read again>\par \end
```

Here's my document that produces the error (minus the content):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% ----------------------------------------------
% Bibliography
% ----------------------------------------------
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
hyperref=true,
style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{final_thesis.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}

% ----------------------------------------------
% Document
% ----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
Content \cite{arduinounorev3}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the final_thesis.bib:

```
@online{arduinounorev3,
author = {Arduino},
title  = {Arduino uno},
year   = {2014},
url    = {http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno},
urldate = {2014-12-01}
}
```

Now when I run LaTeX, BibTeX and LaTeX again it produces the above errors.

I'm using BibLaTeX version 2.9a and Biber 1.9, which should be compatible according to the BibLaTeX manual.

Edit: I'm starting to think this is actually a LaTeX issue

Comment: If I make your document compilable (i.e. exchange `final_thesis.bib` by `biblatex-examples.bib`) and also cite something. Everything works fine. You should try and come up with an MWE that can actually be compiled and that exhibits the problem. You didn't say whether this exact MWE above has the problem on your machine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your example code currently doesn't feature any citation commands, and hence no citation callouts are generated that could give rise to an interaction between `biblatex` and `hyperref`. Please edit your example code so that it actually generates a problem.

Comment: I've edited the question to actually include code that produces the errors on my system.

Comment: Mhhh, still with your `.bib` file it works absolutely fine here. Do you get the problem with the exact example above? Did you try deleting the temporary `.aux` files (and so on).

Comment: @moewe I started with new files in a new folder to be sure, but I still got those errors

Comment: Have you made sure all your packages are up to date? You could add `\listfiles` to the beginning of your document and post the relevant lines of your `.log` file. (But you might want to get rid of `\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}` first, if it does not pertain to the problem at hand.)

Comment: Just tested, those three packages are not the issue. The output of `\listfiles` is [as follows.](http://pastebin.com/1Ewym00c)

Comment: Unfortunately, the information about `biblatex` is missing in your `\listfiles` output, but all the other packages seem to be fine.

Comment: Just tried again, when starting a new document and running LaTeX for the first time I don't get the errors, only after running biber and re-running LaTeX

Comment: I ran the wrong LaTeX file, here's the `\listfiles` output with BibLaTeX: `biblatex.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)` and `biblatex2.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB
)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given error message `Argument of \hyper@anchorstart has an extra }` let me guess, that you have a problem with a special bib file entry, because your given code and bib file compiles without any error or warning on my current MikTeX 2.9 system.

You talked about "errors". So you got more errors? With the given MWE or with your code?  First we have to make sure we are talking about the same code.

So please copy the following MWE into your computer and compile it, run biber and compile twice. And the result is? (for me: no error, no warning except `filecontents`, which is okay). I added package `babel` and used package `filecontents` to include the bib file into this MWE.

MWE:

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{arduinounorev3,
  author  = {Arduino},
  title   = {Arduino uno},
  year    = {2014},
  url     = {http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno},
  urldate = {2014-12-01},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  hyperref=true,
  style=numeric
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}


\begin{document}
Content \cite{arduinounorev3}
\nocite{*}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

On your system this MWE should also compile without problems. If not, you have a problem with your installation. If yes, I guess you have more entrys in your bib file?  Then one of this entrys **above the given one** causes the problem. Add one by one to the MWEs bib file and compile once again. Please check the log for your biber run. Error messages in the `blg` file? Yes? Correct them. No. Then we need more informations ...

My listfiles result is:

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
  report.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size12.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
 spanish.ldf
csquotes.sty    2011/10/22 v5.1d context-sensitive quotations
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
csquotes.def    2011/10/22 v5.1d csquotes generic definitions
csquotes.cfg    
biblatex.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2014/06/25 v2.9a programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
 numeric.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 spanish.lbx    2014/06/25 v2.9a biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
user3287849.bbl
   color.sty    2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
user3287849.out
user3287849.out
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. I did not have a `,` after the urldate.

Comment: @user3287849 - If `urldate` is the last field of the entry, providing a trailing comma should *not* be necessary. Did you maybe make some other changes too?

Comment: Actually, it turns out that the error only occurs with normal LaTeX, and it works when I use PdfLatex

Comment: @user3287849 Do you mean an error with the MWE or with your own code with more bib entrys? If the error(s) occur with the MWE, please add the part with the first error(!) from the log file in your question. Start ten lines before the error message please. If the MWE works try to change my MWE to show the error. And then please add into your question how you compile (do you call latex, pdflatex or lualatex).  I'm not able to recreate with my MWE your error (except I delete one `,` in the bib file (not a last one!))